# kinesis firehose how to disable s3 bucket backup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I deploy a kinesis firehose with http destination in AWS and enabled backup to s3 bucket.
The current configuration is All data but I want to change it to Failed data only. When I look at the console this option is greyed out. Is there a way for me to update it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot disable source record backup at the moment.

From the documentation:

> You can enable source record backup when you create or update your delivery stream. You cannot disable source record backup after you enable it.

(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html#data-transformation-source-record-backup)

Your only option is to delete the stream and re-create it.